# Как вызвать переменную из другого метода

Tags: c#, методы

Есть метод `ReturnWord`, который вызывает случайный элемент из списка и возвращает его в `list[index]`.
Нужен еще один метод который показывает слово из списка, которое было вызвано методом `ReturWord`, не вызывая этот метод.
Не могу понять как сохранить переменную `save` и вызвать ее в другом методе.

```cs
public string save { get; set; }


public string ReturnWord()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        {"Правило" },
        {"Осада" },
        {"Жизнь" },
        {"Никита"},
        {"Ликвидация" },
    };

    var random = new Random();
    int index = random.Next(list.Count);
    save = list[index];
    return list[index];
}

public string SaveReturnWord()
{
    return save;
}
```

---

P.S. 
`ReturnWord` вызываю и всё отлично работает, `SaveReturnWord` в отладке пишет что его значение null.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш лист в скоупе метода, вне метода лист = `null`, вынесите лист в объект как приватный и пользуйтесь

```
private List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    {"Правило" },
    {"Осада" },
    {"Жизнь" },
    {"Никита"},
    {"Ликвидация" },
};
```

Comment: Объявить свойство как приватное?
То несовсем понял

Comment: Создайте список чтобы был виден свойствам и методам класса.

Comment: Ваш ответ не полный, приведите пример реализации того, что имеете в виду.

Comment: А это не важно, что вне метода список не видно, возвращается же не список, а строка. Строку будет видно везде, дело не в этом совсем.

Answer (score 0):

Это ведь зависит от того, как вы вызываете методы этого класса. Если вы будете вызывать их каждый раз создавая новый экземпляр класса, то ничего не запомнится, конечно. Ну, если не сделать переменную `save` статической - одной на все экземпляры класса. Тогда можно и не использовать тот же объект класса - у любого экземпляра будет одно и то же состояние. В этом случае можно и вообще не создавать экземпляры, сделав статичный класс со статичными методами и статичной переменной. Такой подход можно применить, если у вас в программе нужно хранить только одно такое состояние.
Но правильнее всё же создать экземпляр класса и обращаться к его методам. Тогда этот класс запомнит в себе состояние переменной `save`. Таких классов в программе вы можете иметь сколько хотите и каждый экземпляр будет хранить своё собственное случайное состояние.

```
var worldClass1 = new WorldClass();
var worldClass2 = new WorldClass();
Console.WriteLine(worldClass1.ReturnWord());
Console.WriteLine(worldClass2.ReturnWord());
Console.WriteLine(worldClass1.SaveReturnWord());
Console.WriteLine(worldClass2.SaveReturnWord());
// Вывод:
Правило
Жизнь
Правило
Жизнь
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, хотелось-бы узнать чуть подробнее задачу, которая стоит.

Во-вторых, не стоит свойству, которое вы не планируете изменять извне, оставлять сет-эр публичным - делайте его приватным.

В-третьих, вы планируете, чтоб слово рандомилось при создании экземпляра или после вызова метода?

Как я вижу данный код:

```
public class ReturnWord<T>
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public T Element { get; }

    public ReturnWord(List<T> list)
    {
        var rndIndex = rnd.Next(list.Count());
        Element = list.ElementAt(rnd.Index);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, вам нужно передать, при создании экземпляра класса, List с элементами. Рандомное значение будет находиться в свойстве Element.

Пример:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    {"Правило" },
    {"Осада" },
    {"Жизнь" },
    {"Никита"},
    {"Ликвидация" },
};

var returnWord = new ReturnWord(list);
COnsole.WriteLine(returnWord.Element);
```

Писал без VisualStudio, поэтому могут быть опечатки в коде.

Answer (score -1):

в этой строке

```
public  string save { get; set; }
```

поставить static

```
 public static string save { get; set; }
```

Comment: Это решение подойдёт, если такое состояние нужно только одно в программе.